# Select multiple nodes in one xpath.evalutaion call with different names in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to select multiple nodes in one xpath.evalutaion call with different names. I have only figured out how to select one node with the same name and get the content inside those. As in this example i get the `<rrm:indentifier>` content.

```
String linkXPath = "/ds:dataSource/ds:artifact/ds:traceability/ds:links/ds:Link/ds:content/rrm:identifier/text()";
InputSource source = new InputSource(rootServicesResponse.getEntity().getContent());
NodeList attribute = (NodeList)(xpath.evaluate(linkXPath, source, XPathConstants.NODESET));
```

XML

```
<ds:traceability>
  <ds:links>
    <ds:Link type="Decomposition">
      <rrm:title>Parent Of</rrm:title>
      <ds:linkType>
        https://localhost:9443/rm/types/_cyuacfNmEeatIKybawF-9Q
      </ds:linkType>
      <ds:isParentLink>true</ds:isParentLink>
      <ds:isChildLink>false</ds:isChildLink>
      <rrm:relation>
        https://localhost:9443/rm/resources/_qmYQMfNpEeatIKybawF-9Q
      </rrm:relation>
      <rrm:identifier>1</rrm:identifier>
      <ds:content>
        <rrm:title>test</rrm:title>
        <rrm:identifier>1</rrm:identifier>
        <rrm:description/>
        <rrm:format>Text</rrm:format>
        <ds:artifactFormat>Requirement</ds:artifactFormat>
      </ds:content>
    </ds:Link>
  <ds:Link type="Decomposition">
    <rrm:title>Parent Of</rrm:title>
    <ds:linkType>
        https://localhost:9443/rm/types/_cyuacfNmEeatIKybawF-9Q
    </ds:linkType>
    <ds:isParentLink>true</ds:isParentLink>
    <ds:isChildLink>false</ds:isChildLink>
    <rrm:relation>
      https://localhost:9443/rm/resources/_RQWuYQJXEeeQ67tlGaw8LA
    </rrm:relation>
    <rrm:identifier>12</rrm:identifier>
    <ds:content>
       <rrm:title>kest</rrm:title>
       <rrm:identifier>12</rrm:identifier>
       <rrm:description/>
       <rrm:format>Text</rrm:format>
       <ds:artifactFormat>Requirement</ds:artifactFormat>
    </ds:content>
   </ds:Link>
  </ds:links>
</ds:traceability>
```

Is there a way to select every element inside, for example, each `<ds:content>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*` to reference element of any name, for example :

```
//ds:Link/ds:content/*
```

Or if you want to specify multiple element names in one XPath :

```
//ds:Link/ds:content/*[self::rrm:title|self::rrm:identifier|self::rrm:format]
```